# Magento: How to know many blocks are cached

Tags: caching, magento

i cached my custom block inherit of  Mage_Core_Block_Template. I cached the bloc with the next constructor:

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime'    => 120,
        'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG, Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG),
                ));
    }
```

Right, i want verify that this block is cached. How i can list all block cached in my Magento.
I want a similar instruction:

```
var_dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());exit;
```

to see all layout , in blocks cached.
thx.

Comment: I'd love to see some kind of detailed cache information interface in the Mage admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `cache_key` for your block:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_key' => 'some_static_or_dynamic_key', // can be static or dynamic
        'cache_lifetime'    => 120,
        'cache_tags'        => array(
            Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG,
            Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG),
        )
    );
}
```

And then you can ensure that block is cached by calling:

```
Mage::app()->loadCache('your_cache_key');
```

Here is good article about [blocks caching](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput).

Comment: i try var_dump(Mage::app()->loadCache('footer_locale'));exit; and this return false

Comment: What if you will try to modify template for this block - do you see your changes on the frontend?

Comment: the block is cached but only for my comprehension of the Magento cache behavior i want to list of Magento block cached

Comment: can you show me an example of the use of Mage::app()->loadCache('') for footer please?

Answer (score 0):

To see if Magento created your cache, you could search for the file that contains in it's name your tags in the var folder. Also make sure you have your cache activated for this to work.